# Как див разбить на 2 равные части на чистом CSS без добавления блоков HTML

Tags: html, css

У меня есть блок, который приходит с вордпресса, мне нужно его разделить на две равные части, чтобы было 50% слева и 50% справа. Разбить блок я не могу, поэтому нужно через Css. Блок приходит не один, там шаблонные страницы и всегда блоки разные, поэтому фиксированую высоту не получится сделать, нужно чтобы это было автоматически. `display:flex`, `flex-wrap:wrap` не подходит, так как блок выходит в строку, а после переходит на новую строку, а мне нужно чтобы он был в высоту, а после переходил на новый столбик. Вот пример кода, который нужно разбить.

```html
<div class="container__inner service__price">
    <h2 class="h2 service__price__title">С нами выгодно, надежно и удобно</h2>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="service__price__inner">
                <p class="p__light service__price__text">Если есть печальный опыт построения рекламной акции, и Вы остались недовольны ее результатами, потратили бюджет попусту, это значит, что не повезло с директологом. Специалисты компания «BPM CLOUD» сертифицированы в Google AdWords. Они займутся Вашим проектом и проведут его по всем позициям от начала до конца и предложат оптимальное исполнение для любого бюджета – от десяти тысяч до миллиона рублей.</p>
                <p class="p__light service__price__text">Заказав рекламу Google AdWords у нас, Вы получите договорные гарантии, оформленные письменно, а также отчетные документы. Все условия обсуждаем заранее и изменяем только по согласованию.</p>
                <p class="p__light service__price__text">У нас можно заказать настройку контекстной рекламы Google, а также аудит имеющейся. Мы поможем понять, что не так с рекламой, как сделать ее лучше, быстрее и результативнее. Также Вы и сами будете иметь доступ к личному кабинету и сервисам Гугл и контролировать процесс.</p>
                <p class="p__light service__price__text">Проконсультируем и научим необходимому и достаточному объему навыков для работы с рекламными инструментами, дадим базовые тезисы по маркетингу и бизнес-технологиям в медиа, предложим оптимальную стратегию, перспективный медиаплан и создадим портрет целевой аудитории.</p>

                <p class="p__light service__price__text">Когда реклама заработает, и мы поймем, что постороннее вмешательство в процесс больше не требуется, прямо скажем об этом. Мы не заинтересованы намеренно затягивать сотрудничество, ведь в помощи нуждаются и другие клиенты.</p>
                <p class="p__light service__price__text">Если хотите получать моментальный возврат инвестиций после запуска рекламной кампании, обращайтесь к нам за созданием идеально проработанной рекламы под Ваши задачи.</p>
                <p class="p__light service__price__text">Подробнее узнать условия сотрудничества, получить первичную консультацию и рассчитать стоимость рекламной кампании можно, позвонив или написав на электронный адрес. Обращайтесь – рады Вам в любое время.</p>
                <p class="p__light service__price__text">Контекстная реклама Google – умный помощник в бизнесе!</p>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /container -->
</div><!-- /service__price -->
```

Comment: WordPress тут ни при чём.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй columns:

```
.service__price__inner {columns: 2; column-gap:2em;}
.service__price__inner p {break-inside: avoid; }
```